# What does "You have exceeded the maximum group join rate. Please try again later." mean?

Tags: google-groups

I get this message every time I try to join Google Groups.

Comment: Did you take a look at this: http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/apps/YvSoi6U5pzk/qzLZd7za1_wJ
"I guess you can put max 25 at one go, give it a shot with 25 first, and straight away 2nd go with 25."

Comment: Is this your group? Or just a group you wanna join? Maybe the moderator has places maximum number of group members. Try contacting the group moderator for more information.